# Ionic slides update() function

Tags: ionic-framework

I am generating `ion-slides` asynchronously. However I believe I need to use `update()` function.

Below is the api section: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#update

I am not sure how to use this function.

Could someone show me how to use this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

this is how i did it in a past project:

first you have to get the instance of your slide:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.sliderInitialized", function(event, data){
    //self is my controller
    self.sliderInstance = data.slider;
    //slidesLoaded is a custom var i used to store loaded slides
    if(self.slidesLoaded.length < 1){
        //initialisation stuff, or filling content
        //...
        self.sliderInstance.update();
    }
});
```

then you can call it anytime you add a slide for example, in my case i did a dynamic next slide loading:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd", function(event, data){
    var index_t = self.sliderInstance.activeIndex;
    self.loadSlide(index_t + 1);
    self.sliderInstance.update();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It looks like your project was with ionic version 1. I will give your method a try! Thanks!

Comment: yes, you didn't specify ionic 2 so i thought this would be useful. The logic should be the same or approximately in new versions

Comment: Mhmm. I am trying to somewhat copy the structure of your code and see I can duplicate the method in the new version. Although some aspects are substantially different from the v1, hopefully I can figure this out. haha